# Is it possible to scroll in a cell of a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have some records in my gridview. But there is a problem in each record, there is one cell which contains a HUGE amount of data. I still want to display data and allow the users to scroll down to read (if they're interested). Is there a possibility to allow scrolling in that cell?

EDIT:

This is the css I refer to:

```
    .AspNet-GridView
    {
        overflow: auto;
        height:400px;
    }
    .AspNet-GridView table thead tr th
    {
        height:20px;
        position:relative;
    }
    .AspNet-GridView table tbody
    {
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

EDIT 2:
this is the gridview and I want The column with the headertext body to allow scrolling.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvAanvragen" 
    OnPageIndexChanging="GvAanvragen_PageIndexChanging" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" 
    PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GvAanvragen_SelectedIndexChanged" 
        CssClass="AspNet-GridView">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Subject" DataField="Subject" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Body" DataField="Body" HtmlEncode="false" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sent" DataField="Sent" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: seems like you tried using CSS and it didn't work out? Maybe you missed ".AspNet-GridView table tr td {...}"? You could give it a try. But it might be necessary to have a div inside the td, which you can achieve using Naveed's answer.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any idea of how to achieve what Naveed said :s. How do I add a template column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To add to Naveed's answer, now that you've posted your original code: http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs has a good example of a data bound template field:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In your case, just replace the line

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Body" DataField="Body" HtmlEncode="false" />
```

by the code Naveed provided, and add the databinding as in this example, and you endup with something like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Body">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="overflow:auto; height: 100px;">
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Body")%>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

If you don't want to use a label, then use a literal control instead:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Body")%>' />
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did. But how can I get the text of that cell. Because now that cell contains a label and not a text anymore.

Comment: @Massimo: I'd need some clarification of what you mean by "text". Isn't the text in the label a "text" in your sense?

Comment: @Massimo: In case you're speaking about a text *box* to edit the content: Refer to the link I posted, it also displays how to use the `<EditTemplate>`

Comment: The cell contains a label not a text! If I access the value of the cell, I will get the label!!! we're discussing this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270196/2-problems-how-to-hide-a-column-but-still-retrieve-its-values-how-to-access-a-l

Comment: @Massimo: If you don't want to use a label, then use a literal control. :-) Do you ever use google to find solutions? I'm editing my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

You can use Template Column and place a div inside it with `style="overflow:auto;"`

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <div style="overflow:auto; height: 100px;"><Your Content here></div> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: +1 When reading the question, that's pretty much what I thought of as well.

Comment: @Massimo: Instead of `<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Body" DataField="Body" HtmlEncode="false" />` you add the code above. You only need to replace "<Your Content here>" by some data binding content. You'll find examples for that on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a template column and inside of that column put all your content inside a div with overflow set (refer to CSS overflow).