# How to get Text value of Label-controls in cells of GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, label

In my GridView there is a column containing Label-controls as value. I need to know how to access each Label-control to get its Text value. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If your question has led to you another problem, please either update this question (if it is closely related) or ask a new one after posting what got you past this point. Additionally, moderator flags are not for disputing the technical merit of any given answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store its value in a hidden field and place it in any other column. Then when you retrieve that row value you can access that hiddenfield value

Comment: Are you displaying all the columns of your query or you have specify them using gridview columns?

Comment: at the moment the columns are specified using gridview.

Comment: Then remove that column and place a label in any other column and set its text property to the value of that column. like this  Text="'<%#Databinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ColumnName")) %>'"

Answer (score 1):

handle selectedIndexChanged event and in it do

```
string text = ((Label)grid.SelectedRow.Cells[cellIndex]).Text;

string text = grid.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text; // this should do the trick
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label'

Comment: hmm, if you remove the cast and just try getting the Text property?